# Initial and maximum recomended Heap size on server

Tags: java, glassfish, heap-memory

I have several applications running on a Glassfish application server (4.0). I have recorded some statistics of the java memory usage with DataDog, so I am able to see the historic of the used heap memory along with the *initial* and *maximum* constant heap sizes.

[image: Initial, maximum and real heap values]
*The image shows the initial (yellow), maximum (blue) and real (purple) heap values.*

As you can see above, the real heap size is always bellow the initial heap value, so I'm planning to move these parameters to improve the server's performance, but I'm not sure if this is really necessary.

So, I have this doubts:

1. It is worth to modify the heap parameters?
2. If so, which parameters would be generraly correct? (example: initial value 100 mb above your average real heap value, and the maximum, twice that number).

I guess this questions hold true talking of a tomcat, JBoss or any servlet-oriented server.

Any help will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends. Also, your image doesn't display as of my answer.**

If your machines are super memory hungry and you are an individual without unlimited income, I think your approach would be fine. I would recommend a slightly higher arbitrary percentage to start with, such as 50%, to provide a bit of wiggle room. Continue to analyze the memory usage and adjust your maximum accordingly. I don't see any reason to set memory usage below default.

Otherwise, you can be much more gratuitous and provide 100-200% extra memory, in case your application experiences sudden heavy load.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the image.

Comment: Ok, so your memory usage seems far below your maximum, but from what I know, standard values are usually powers of 2. So 512MB would be my recommendation here unless you really need to handle a lot of requests/load at once, in which case I would set it to 1024MB. Leave your minimum as is.